# What does :: and ' mean in oCaml?

Tags: ocaml

What does`x :: xs'` mean?
I dont have much functional experience but IIRC in F#  1 :: 2 :: 3 :: [];; creates an array of [1,2,3]
so what does the ' do?

```
let rec sum xs =
  match xs with
    | [] -> 0
    | x :: xs' -> x + sum xs'
```

Comment: `::` means 2 camel humps, `'` means 1 hump!

Comment: Ok a decent comment: http://merd.sourceforge.net/pixel/language-study/syntax-across-languages-per-language/OCaml.html  I don't use oCaml, but there's a full syntax list you my find useful, even if there's no real context to it.

Comment: it is a list not an array, they are Waaaaay different when it comes to functional programming.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think *sepp2k* already answered most of the question, but I'd like to add a couple of points that may clarify how F#/OCaml compiler interprets the code and explain some common uses.

**Regarding the `'` symbol** - this is just a part of a name (a valid identifier starts with a letter and then contains one or more letters, numbers or `'` symbols). It is usually used if you have a function or value that is very similar to some other, but is in some way *new* or *modified*.

- In your example, `xs` is a list that should be summed and the pattern matching decomposes the list and gives you a new list (without the first element) that you need to sum, so it is called `xs'`
- Another frequent use is when declaring a local utility function that implements the functionality and takes an additional parameter (typically, when writing tail-recursive code):

  ```
  let sum list =
    let rec sum' list res = 
      match list with
      | [] -> res
      | x::xs -> sum' xs (res + x)
    sum' list 0
  ```

However, I think there is usually a better name for the function/value, so I try to avoid using `'` when writing code (I think it isn't particularly readable and moreover, it doesn't colorize correctly on StackOverflow!)

**Regarding  the `::` symbol** - as already mentioned, it is used to create lists from a single element and a list (`1::[2;3]` creates a list `[1;2;3]`). It is however worth noting that the symbol can be used in two different ways and it is also interpreted in two different ways by the compiler.

When creating a list, you use it as an operator that constructs a list (just like when you use `+` to add two numbers). However, when you use it in the `match` construct, it is used as a *pattern*, which is a different syntactic category - the pattern is used to *decompose* the list into an element and the remainder and it succeeds for any non-empty list:

```
// operator
let x = 0
let xs = [1;2;3]
let list = x::xs

// pattern
match list with
| y::ys -> // ...
```

Comment: The :: is called the cons operator, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You forgot to declare `sum'` function recursive. Also, there should be a `in` keyword after the match.

Comment: Thanks - I added the `rec` keyword. I wrote the code in F#, which is whitespace-sensitive and doesn't require `in` keywords.

Answer (score 6):

The ' is simply part of the variable name. And yes `foo :: bar`, where foo is an element of type a and bar is a list of type a, means "the list that has foo as its first element, followed by the elements of bar". So the meaning of the match statement is:

If xs is the empty list, the value is 0. If xs is the list containing the item x followed by the items in `xs'` the value is `x + sum xs'`. Since `x` and `xs'` are fresh variables, this has the effect that for any non empty list, `x` will be assigned the value of the first element and `xs'` will be assigned the list containing all other elements.

Comment: it sounds like i can write x :: remainder' instead. But what does ' specifically mean? that xs is a list? would x::xs not have xs as the remainder of the list?

Comment: ' is just another character that is allowed in names. there is no difference between remainder and remainder' except that the last one is pronounced "remainder prime".

Comment: @acidzombie24: The ' means nothing. It's just part of the name. You could as well write `x :: foo`. You can't however write `x :: xs` in your code because the name `xs` is already taken by the parameter to sum. That's all.

Comment: The usage of "'" in variables comes from the academic community who like to refer to variables as x, x' (pronounced x-prime), f(x), f'(x), etc.

Comment: Well, you *can* write the pattern `x :: xs`, it's just that you will no longer be able to access the original `xs` inside that branch.

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said, the ' is a carryover from mathematics where x' would be said as "x prime"

Answer (score 1):

It's idiomatic in ML-family languages to name a variable `foo'` to indicate that it's somewhat related to another variable `foo`, especially in recursions like your code sample. Just like in imperative languages you use `i`, `j` for loop indices. This naming convention may be a little surprising since `'` is typically an illegal symbol for identifiers in C-like languages.

Answer (score 0):

> What does `x :: xs'` mean?

If you have two variables called `x` and `xs'` then `x :: xs'` creates a new list with `x` prepended onto the front of `xs'`.

> I dont have much functional experience but IIRC in F# 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: [];; creates an array of [1,2,3]

Not quite. It's a list.

> so what does the ' do?

It is treated as an alphabetical character, so the following is equivalent:

```
let rec sum xs =
  match xs with
  | [] -> 0
  | x :: ys -> x + sum ys
```

Note that `::` is technically a type constructor which is why you can use it in both patterns and expressions.